A question about the physical meaning of Fourier Transform
I'm learning Fourier transform recently. For a periodic function $f\in L^{1}(\mathbb{R})$ (with period 1 for example), we have Fourier series
$$f(x) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}a_{n}e^{2\pi i nx}$$
where
$$a_{n} = \int_{[0,1]}f(x)e^{2 \pi i nx}dx$$
For a nonperiodic function $f\in L^{1}(\mathbb{R})$, we have Fourier transform
$$\hat{f}(\lambda) = \mathcal{F}(f)(\lambda) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)e^{-i\lambda x}dx$$
Then I want to do the same thing to $\hat{f}$
$$\sum_{\lambda \in \mathbb{R}}\hat{f}(\lambda)e^{-i\lambda x}$$
And does this sum make any sense (physical meaning)?

3Blue1Brown does a good job of explaining this I think.

$f(x)$ in the none periodic case is an integral not a sum.

When you're thinking "sum over reals", you're probably thinking of an integral.  The thing you may have to ponder is what differential to use -- is there a change of variable hiding in here whose derivative/Jacobian we need to insert?

Also, I ge\ot much insight when I realized your formula for $a_n$ is taking the dot product of $f$ and then $n^{\text{th}}$ basis function of the Fourier basis.  Then $f$ can be reconstructed by multiplying the basis functions by the dot products we just took and adding all those up (either a summation for discrete basis or integral for continuous basis).

I don't believe your sum over the reals makes sense. You can integrate over the reals, but you can't sum over the reals which are uncountably infinite. But this answer illustrates that a function $f(x)$ can be recovered from its Fourier transform $F(\omega)=\mathcal{F}_x[f(x)](\omega)$ by evaluating $F(\omega)$ only at rational values of $\omega$.

Using slightly different Fourier parameters where the Fourier transform of $f(x)$ is defined as
$$F(\omega)=\mathcal{F}_x[f(x)](\omega)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\, e^{-2 \pi i \omega x}\, dx\tag{1}$$
then when the Fourier inversion theorem holds I believe $f(x)$ can be evaluated as the nested Fourier series representation
$$f(x)=\mathcal{F}^{-1}_{\omega}[F(\omega)](x)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} F(\omega)\, e^{2 \pi i x \omega} \, d\omega\\=\lim\limits_{N, f\to\infty}\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^N \frac{\mu(2 n-1)}{2 n-1} \left(\frac{1}{2} \sum\limits_{k=-2 f (2 n-1)}^{2 f (2 n-1)} (-1)^k\, \cos\left(\frac{\pi k}{2 n-1}\right)\, F\left(\frac{k}{4 n-2}\right) e^{\frac{i \pi k x}{2 n-1}}\\-\frac{1}{8} \sum\limits_{k=-4 f (2 n-1)}^{4 f (2 n-1)} (-1)^k\, F\left(\frac{k}{8 n-4}\right) e^{\frac{i \pi k x}{4 n-2}}\right)\right)\tag{2}$$
where $\mu(n)$ is the Möbius function and the parameter $f$ in the upper evaluation limits of the two inner sums over $k$ is assumed to be a positive integer.

Formula (2) above is equivalent to formula (5) in my related MSO question which provides information on its derivation.

One of the results I find interesting is that I believe $\Gamma(s)$ can be evaluated as
$$\Gamma(s)=f(-i (s-1))\,,\quad\Re(s)>0\tag{3}$$
using formula (2) above where
$$F(\omega)=\mathcal{F}_t[\Gamma(1+i t)](\omega)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \Gamma(1+i t)\, e^{-2 \pi i \omega t} \, dt=2 \pi\, e^{2 \pi \omega-e^{2 \pi \omega}}\tag{4}$$
is the Fourier transform of $f(t)=\Gamma(1+i t)$.

Figure (1) below illustrates formula (3) for $\Gamma(s)$ above in orange overlaid on the blue reference function $\Gamma(s)$ where formula (2) referenced by formula (3) is evaluated at $f=10$ and $N=20$.

Figure (1): Illustration of formula (3) for $\Gamma(s)$ in orange overlaid on blue reference function $\Gamma(s)$

The following table of discrete evaluation points provides insight into the precision of the evaluation of formula (3) for $\Gamma(s)$ illustrated in Figure (1) above using the same evaluation limits $f=10$ and $N=20$ for formula (2) that was used to create the plot in the figure.
$$\begin{array}{cccc}
 s & \Gamma(s) & \Gamma(s)\text{ (formula (3))} & \Gamma(s)-\Gamma(s)\text{ (formula (3))} \\
 \frac{1}{2} & 1.77245 & 1.77245 & -4.23759 \times 10^{-14} \\
 1 & 1. & 1. & 1.03337 \times 10^{-16} \\
 \frac{3}{2} & 0.886227 & 0.886227 & 2.6914 \times 10^{-16} \\
 2 & 1. & 1. & 8.90943 \times 10^{-17} \\
 \frac{5}{2} & 1.32934 & 1.32934 & -2.81208 \times 10^{-16} \\
 3 & 2. & 2. & -7.61991 \times 10^{-16} \\
 \frac{7}{2} & 3.32335 & 3.32335 & -5.75268 \times 10^{-16} \\
 4 & 6. & 6. & -1.51723 \times 10^{-15} \\
 \frac{9}{2} & 11.6317 & 11.6317 & -7.35523 \times 10^{-16} \\
 5 & 24. & 24. & -1.71009 \times 10^{-14} \\
\end{array}$$
